# Send output of batch file in email as attached file with Outlook 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, windows-task-scheduler

I have a java script which produces its output in a separated text file. I need to send that text file as attached file in an email with outlook 2010, everyday at 6pm. Is that possible with windows task scheduler ? or I need here some other tool.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't out of the box. You'll need to either write the script by yourself or use third-party software for that.